# MySQL Table - Large Gaps in ID Field

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to MySQL so please forgive me if this question is too "basic".

We imported data from another database to MySQL. In two of the tables, there are large gaps in the ID field. For example, in one table, IDs 1 to 5438 have smaller gaps but then the next few IDs are 5823, 6612, 7880, 8577, 12541 and it continues like this to 54189. Then it jumps to 441739936 and continues to increase with large gaps in between to 3872082950. I'm assuming that when we start adding data to this table the next ID will be 3872082951 (it's set to auto-increment). The table only has 5234 rows.

My questions are:

1. Is there any problem with having these large gaps? Will it negatively impact query response time? Are there any other negative side effects of having these large gaps?
2. Is it fine to leave it as is or are we better off renumbering the IDs so they are sequential without gaps?

Comment: So if the ID column is set to auto-increment and the last ID is 3872082950, will it start to auto-increment from that point (next IDs would be 3872082951, 3872082952, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem or penalty with allowing large gaps to remain in the database. There's no impact to performance. Auto-increment id's must be unique, but there's no need for them to be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it wont

2) Probably you should not, remember that id can be used to reference a data row in other table, so if you renumber this, you can change the relations.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem having the gaps, as stated by Bill, but be careful to set the correct data type for the field to cope with the size of the value (bigint, etc).

You can read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html and find the Numeric Data types here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html